# Difference between multilinguists and polyglots

Tags: differences, vocabulary

> **A multilinguist  is one who speaks or knows many languages.**
>
> **A polyglot is one who speaks or knows many languages**

What is the difference between a multilingual , multlinguist and a polyglot? can we call all multilinguals polyglots?

Here are the two links.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/multilinguist

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polyglot

Comment: On ELU, reasonably accessible supporting references, linked and attributed, are expected to accompany questions. Have two or three respectable dictionaries no usage notes say on possible differences? Do denotations seem to overlap to a large degree?

Comment: Nothing.  It's called synonymy.

Comment: Are you asking about *multilinguist* or *multilingual*? Or both? In comparing them to *polyglot*, it seems a bit strange to provide identical definitions and then ask if they're different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google ngram viewer shows that *multilingual* only appeared about 1940 and has gradually overtaken the older *polyglot*.

I suspect that because the latinate word was more closely related to English words, it was more acceptable to the post-war generation from non-upper class backgrounds that was receiving higher education for the first time. As well as perhaps not knowing what *glot* meant (lacking Greek, like me) they probably felt it sounded somewhat unpleasant — an aural association with *glob* and *clot*.

Answer (score 3):

Latin *multi* = Greek *poly* = English *many*

Latin *lingua* = Greek *glotta* = English *tongue*

The difference in English usage is that "multilingual" is an adjective, while "polyglot" can be an adjective, but more commonly it is a noun.

Comment: The noun 'multilingual' also exists, and OP is obviously looking for differences in **meaning**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. Are you saying that "difference in usage" is not the same as "difference in meaning"?

Comment: @fdb He's right.  It can be different.

Comment: I think  all multilinguals  are not polyglots.Difference in usage  is different from meaning.I am expecting  a better  answer.